# Using helper to retrieve subcollections from Users

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, meteor-blaze

I have a project where each User can have several Expenses. Expenses are stored in the User document.

For example, a user's document looks like this:

> {
>    "username": "Joe Bloggs",
>    "expenses": [
>     {
>       "title": "bucket of paint",
>       "price": 9.99
>     },
>     {
>       "title": "large mop",
>       "price": 5.49
>     }
>    ]
>  }

I'm trying to build a helper that outputs each Expense of every User, which would end up like this on the page:

```
Joe Bloggs | Bucket of paint | 9.99
Joe Bloggs | Large mop | 5.49
Cynthia Smith | Small paintbrush | 3.99
```

If I were just trying to get a list of users, I'd do something like this:

```
Template.Expenses.helpers({

  allExpenses(){
  var allUsers = Meteor.users.find().fetch();
  return allUsers;

  }

});
```

... so now I have the users in an array, how would I loop through each user to output their Expense details?

Many thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly loop through your users with {{#each}} or {{#each in}}

```
<template name="Expenses">
    {{#each user in allUsers}}
        {{#each expense in user.expense}}
        <p>{{user.username}} | {{expense.title}} | {{expense.price}}</p>
        {{/each}}
    {{/each}}
</template>

Template.Expenses.helper(){
    allUsers(){
        var allUsers = Meteor.users.find().fetch();
        return allUsers;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks - Gaëtan. I'm continually impressed with how easy Meteor can make things.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this solution, explanation in the comments

```js
users = [{ // assuming you have something like this array
  "username": "Joe Bloggs",
  "expenses": [{
    "title": "bucket of paint",
    "price": 9.99
  }, {
    "title": "large mop",
    "price": 5.49
  }]
}, {
  "username": "Dave Peterson",
  "expenses": [{
    "title": "Small Brush",
    "price": 4.59
  }, {
    "title": "Stud finder",
    "price": 19.99
  }]
}];
var expenses = [];
users.forEach(function(currentUser) { // loop over users
  currentUser.expenses.forEach(function(currentExpense) { // loop over current users expenses
    var newExpense = { // create a new expense with needed properties
      username: currentUser.username,
      title: currentExpense.title,
      price: currentExpense.price
    };
    expenses.push(newExpense); // add new expense to expenses array
  });
});

// print the expenses as needed
expenses.forEach(function(expense){
 console.log([expense.username, expense.title, expense.price].join(" | "))
});
```

Comment: here you have use a console log but I think the @H Capello ask how it write inside a helper and how to show it inside the template.Here you have use pure javascript

Comment: I guess i did not fully understand your question. Either way you can still use this approach to transform users then show them in the template.